# Output Test names in unittest discover

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm running Python unittest using the discover mode:

```
 % python -m unittest discover
```

The system prints a dot for each test, but I'd rather see a test name.

Is there an option that makes this happen?

Answer (score 5):

The verbose flag (`-v`) is what you're looking for:

```
$ python -m unittest discover -v
test_a (tests.test_a.TestA) ... ok
test_b (tests.test_b.TestB) ... ok
...
```

For more options, check:

```
$ python -m unittest --help
usage: python -m unittest [-h] [-v] [-q] [--locals] [-f] [-c] [-b]
                          [tests [tests ...]]

positional arguments:
   tests           a list of any number of test modules, classes and test
                   methods.

optional arguments:
   -h, --help      show this help message and exit
   -v, --verbose   Verbose output
   -q, --quiet     Quiet output
   --locals        Show local variables in tracebacks
   -f, --failfast  Stop on first fail or error
   -c, --catch     Catch Ctrl-C and display results so far
   -b, --buffer    Buffer stdout and stderr during tests

 ...
```